# Symfony console command cache directory

Tags: symfony, cmd

I use the symfony3 framework and want to import csv files with a cronjob. For this i try this cmd:

```
bin/console project:type:import
```

And in the impoter is using the cache. But know it writes all cached files to the project root directory. When i use this:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return dirname(__FILE__) . '/../var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}
```

In the `AppKernel.php` it is also not working. What can i do?

Comment: Please share your command.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use '/var/cache/' instead '/../var/cache/' ?

Comment: This is also not working - this is some absolute relative path bug. The source file from the cmd run is not like the app file in the web directory. So you need to add a case for cmd tasks maybe. I go forward and hope to find the solution.

Comment: I think the problem is taht the cmd runner is not using the getCacheDir from AppKernel.php. It is triggerd but also when is use absolute server path it is not working.